# Cannot resolve PubNub

Tags: pubnub

I can´t use PubNub in my Android application.

Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile group: 'com.pubnub', name: 'pubnub', version: '4.0.5'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.7.2'
}
```

In MainActivity.java:

```
import com.pubnub.api.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
//...
 private Pubnub pubnub;  // CANNOT RESOLVE !
//...
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Ok In the latest version is PubNub not pubnub.

Comment: Now I have some problems with setSubscribeKey (not recognized). PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
    pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey("my_key");
    private PubNub pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);

Comment: Can you copy/paste your code into your question above. I don't trust code in the comments because I can't be certain that you didn't type it in and just do a reverse-typo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *case issue*:

`Pubnub` should be `PubNub`

Also, you have two versions of PubNub SDK in there:

```
compile group: 'com.pubnub', name: 'pubnub', version: '4.0.5'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.7.2'
```

So I would assume you are migrating from 3x to 4x and that is the reason you had the Pubnub/PubNub case issue. If you haven't seen it check out the [Android V3 to Android V4 Migration Guide](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/migration-guide-from-v3).